# Confusion with the Lorentz transformation

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, observers

I want to show that ,for me at rest on earth, one clock in movement with speed V ticks slower.
The proper time is the time of the clock at movement, so i do:
$\Delta t=\gamma\Delta t'+\frac {V}{c^2}\gamma \Delta x' $ but $\Delta x'=0$  so its done...
My question is:
Why cant i convert from $\Delta t'=\gamma \Delta t -\frac{V}{c^2}\gamma \Delta x$ like this.
In my conception the transformations work both ways.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Are $\Delta t$ and $\Delta x$ supposed to be in your frame, while $\Delta t'$ and $\Delta x'$ are in the rest frame of the clock?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment because of my low reputation hence I am writing this as an answer 
 I must say that in the latter transformation
$$\Delta t'=\gamma \Delta t -\frac{V}{c^2}\gamma \Delta x$$
where $\Delta x=V \Delta t$ (The event describing the presence of observer in motion at time = $\Delta t$) this implies 

 $$\Delta t'=\gamma \Delta t -\frac{V^2}{c^2}\gamma \Delta t \implies \Delta t'=\gamma(1-\frac{V^2}{c^2}) \Delta t \implies \Delta t'=\frac{\Delta t}{\gamma} $$ which yields the same result

Comment: I assume these were the notations you meant to use